# Significance of Nissl bodies

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

What is the significance of [Nissl bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissl_body)? How are Nissl bodies different from any other RER seen in any other cell of the body?

Comment: Hi there, I think this is a homework question. Please add a refference and try to solve it on you own first. Otherwise you may not get answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissl_body this might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try answer this question.

The origine of this [name](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/Nissl%20bodies) came from article writen by Franz Niessl (18660-1919) and published in 1894. HE found this substance after he visualized it by [nissl stainning](https://openwetware.org/wiki/Nissl_staining) method invented by him.

This basophilic substance was just only find in dendrites of neurons, not axones. It is composed by RNA polyribosomes.

Basicly i am tring to tell you that Niessle body is just older name from old ages of histology.

Niessel body is not diffrent with others rought endoplasmatic reticulum(RER). It same pourpose as normal RER.